# Выделить ячейки таблицы,содержащие простые числа другим цветом

Tags: javascript

2 фрейма: Левый содержит 2 кнопки,правый изначально пустой.При нажатии на кнопку в правом фрейме строится таблица N*N  с числами [1,N^2].
Как выделить ячейки таблицы,содержащие простые числа другим цветом

```
//main.html-главный файл
<HTML> 
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Таблица</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<frameset COLS="35%, *">
<frame name="tab" SRC="frame.html">
<frame name="right"> 
</frameset> 
</HTML>
```

и

```
//frame.html
<HTML> 
<HEAD>
<TITLE>таблица</TITLE> 
<script language="Javascript"> 
function f ()
{ var n = Number (document.forms["form1"].num.value);

var k=1;
var main= top.frames['right'].document; 
main. close()
main.open()
main.writeln('<BODY bgcolor=lightblue><CENTER>'); 
main.writeln('<TABLE COLS='+n+' ROWS='+n+' border=1>');

for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{ main.writeln('<TR>'); 
for (j=0; j<n; j++) 
{main.writeln('<TD> '+Math.round(Number(k++))+
' ')}
main.writeln('</TR>'); }
main.write('</TABLE>'); 
main.writeln('</CENTER><BODY>') ; }
function cl()
{ var main = top.frames['right'].document; 
main. close()
main.open()
main.clear();}
</script> 
</HEAD> 
<BODY>
<FORM name="form1">
Введите N: <input name="num" TYPE="text" size=4> 
<input TYPE="button" value=" OK " onclick="f()"> 
<input TYPE="button" value=" очистить " onclick="cl()"> 
</FORM> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Comment: вы подрабатываете обфускатором?

Comment: у студентов есть встроенный обфускатор, от которого со временем избавляются )

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  main.writeln('<td' + (is_prime(k) ? ' class="prime">' : '>') + k + '</'+ 'td>'); 
  k++;
}
```

А уж как проверять число на простоту - гугл в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Собрал для вас рабочий демонстрационный пример на [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/uLXQS/2/)
А уж как его прикрутить к своему примеру, думаю, вы сами догадаетесь.

[image]

**html**

```
<input id="number" type="text" value="5" />
<button id="main" onclick="bigActionHere();">Click Me!</button>
<div id="table_holder"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function findPrime(num) {
    var output = [];
    for (j = 2; j <= num; j++) {
        for (k = 2; k < j; k++) {
            if (j % k === 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (k === j) {
            output.push(j);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

function bigActionHere() {
    var table_holder = document.getElementById('table_holder'),
        n = document.getElementById('number').value,
        k = 1,
        primes = findPrime(n*n),
        content = '';
    console.log(primes);
    content = '<table cols="'+n+'" rows="'+n+'" border="1">';
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        content += '<tr>';
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {    
            content += '<td'+(inArray(k, primes) ? ' class="prime">' : '>')+k+'</td>';
            k++;
        }
        content += '</tr>';
    }
    content += '</table>';
    table_holder.innerHTML = content;
}
```

**css**

```
.prime {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Наверное, для небольших значений `n` можно и в разреженном массиве простые хранить, шустрей будет :) Да и в findPrime запоминать где в прошлый раз остановились и в следующий раз только добивать массив, если нужно.  Но это уже так, мелочи :)